# How to remove \hyphenpenalty & \pretolerance influence on section/subsection headers

Tags: latex, header, alignment, miktex

In my latex document i've set `\hyphenpenalty=15000` and `\pretolerance=10000` to remove word hyphenation and make text bounds even.

But I can't disable this effect for section/subsection headers. All headers looks badly due to big spaces between words.

---

[image]

---

Are there any solution to disable `\hyphenpenalty=15000` and `\pretolerance=10000` effect for headers?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [titlesec package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/) helps you. It let's you define commands to invoke at each sectioning command. Even if it is thought mainly to change the look, it might do the job by adding some lines that change the valuese before the heading and change back the values after the heading.